# WKT coordinate inner order (long,lat)

Tags: well-known-text, specification

In an open-source tracking project that uses WKT in its API, we have a debate about what is the correct order for representing geographical coordinates.
Lat and then Long or Long and than Lat.

In most popular libraries and documentation I saw, the prevalent order is Long first (Long, Lat).

But looking through the official documentation of WKT I cannot locate the official order.

Can someone point me to the specific documentation or other qualified sources of information?

Comment: {X,Y} order if the only order I've seen or used. If it's not written down then there are exceptions that make the opposite valid. KML and a few others make an explicit order; others like GML force you tag the values, which makes them that much more inefficient. I doubt you'll get a definitive answer, but you'd need a really good reason to not use {lon,lat}.

Comment: MySQL 8 started to use WKT in the official EPSG order. All other software that I know are using long/lat or easting/northing order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the axis order for any  coordinate reference system where EPSG is the authority, you should use their registry `https://epsg.org/home.html`

For example for epsg:4326 (`https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/4326`).

The WKT output shows that for EPSG:4326 the axis order is lat/long

```
GEODCRS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
  CS[ellipsoidal,2],
    AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
    AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
  ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Most EPSG geographic coordinate systems follow the latitude then longitude, coordinate axis order, following the default of `ISO 6709 Standard representation of geographic point location by coordinates`

> Order, positive direction, and units of coordinates are supposed to be defined by the CRS. When CRS identification is missing, the data must be interpreted by the following conventions:
>
> Latitude comes before longitude
>
> North latitude is positive
>
> East longitude is positive
>
> Fraction of degrees is preferred in digital data exchange, while sexagesimal notation is tolerated for compatibility

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709

Comment: I do not quite agree with WKT. The standard http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355 does not say much about the coordinate order and majority of sofware that deal with WKT use systematically longitude/latitude or easting/northing order. It may be wrong but changing the order would mainly add confusion.

Comment: @user30184 The Simple Features specification states that axes order must be interpreted according to the CRS. It is true that some software packages do not comply to the specification, but that does not justify insisting on this mistake. Other standards like GeoSPARQL or GML are even more strict in this regard, as are other ISO specifications.

Comment: This discussion does not seem to forward a bit and I know that I repeat my own words. The first WKT standard from 1999 did not say anything about axis order, just that there are "x" and "y". It was later added, without making a new WKT version, "The interpretation of the coordinates is subject to the coordinate reference systems associated to the point". Currently it is impossible to say what the WKT `POINT (40 50)` means without external information about the CRS, and when the WKT was written. GML of course is another story, and is has an explicit way to include CRS and GML version.

Comment: @nmtoken, when I visit the link `https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/4326`, I don't see the words "ORDER[1]" anywhere in the WKT description of the CRS.  Did you add those terms yourself?

Comment: @bixb0012, I didn't add them I copied the text at the time.

Comment: @nmtoken, OK, thanks for clarifying.  It is interesting that IOGP would alter/change the WKT2 representation to drop explicit ORDER statements.  There doesn't seem to be a paper trail that it was done, but it was obviously done since those statements aren't there any longer when the web page is loaded.  From a practical perspective it doesn't change anything because WKT2 states that axis order is implied by order of AXIS statements when ORDER statements are not included, but it was still an odd change in my mind for them to make without documentation, at least that I can find.

Comment: I agree it's odd; if you look at the HTML page https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html and view details/expand the `Coordinate System:  
Ellipsoidal 2D CS. Axes: latitude, longitude. Orientations: north, east. UoM: degree ` part you can see that order is still stated.  Possibly the issue has arisen because the order is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

This whole discussion seems confusing. I am using PostGIS/QGIS 4326 and am writing wkt point geometries as POINT(long lat). Been doing it for years with success.